# Android purgeable bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, save

When creating purgeable `Bitmap` via `BitmapFactory`, its raw binary data is stored somewhere in the object in case the `Bitmap` needs to be recreated. How can I access this data and save it on SD card? The point is that BitmapFactory used `inSampleSize` param to scale it, but I need to save it in original size. Such information is still accessible via stored undecoded binary data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking through Android source code reveals it's impossible.